# iOS inApp purchase, how to identify he product buy

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have an app for reading newspaper.. with in-app purchase..every product is an edition of the paper.

When the user bought an edition i don't know how to tell to app store what edition was bought.
How can i record this information? there are metadata that i can send to appStore?

Answer (score 0):

The user can bought something in your application only through AppStore.

In other words, you send AppStore transaction with specified `product identificator` of you In-App Purchase, then AppStore process the transaction and then inform your transaction observer about ending of transaction.